# What value do I set a Django form's ChoiceField's initial value to be invalid?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I have a Django form with two ChoiceFields.  I will refer to them as CF1 and CF2.  Now, CF1 displays a list of car models.  CF2 remains blank until a selection is picked in CF1 and then my JQuery takes over to populate CF2 with the makes for that car model.  Example: Nissan -> Maxima.

```
from django import forms

cars = (('', '----'), ('1', 'Toyota'), ('2', 'Nissan'), ('3', 'Ford'), ('4', 'Honda'))

class SearchForm(forms.Form)
     model = forms.ChoiceField(choices=cars required=True)
     make = forms.ChoiceField(required=True) 

     def clean(self):
         cleaned_data = super(SearchForm, self).clean()
         mo = cleaned_data.get("model")
         ma = cleaned_data.get("make")

         if not mo or not ma:
             raise forms.ValidationError("blahblah")
         return cleaned_data
```

The form should be considered valid *only if* the user makes a selection in both ChoiceFields.  However, the form that I submit is always invalid, regardless of if I left selections blank or not.  Now, I know that for a ChoiceField, there is always a default initial value, right?  But is there a way to set a valid flag of a ChoiceField to be invalid until something is selected at which point that flag is toggled to be valid?

**view.py**

```
def car_info(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.GET) # a form bound to the GET data
    if form.is_valid(): # never seems to be pass this test
        return render(request, "car.html", {})
    else: # always ends up here
        form = SearchForm() # an unbound form
        return render(request, "find.html", {'form': form})
```

**find.html**

```
    {% if form.errors %}
        <div class="err">{{ form.errors | pluralize  }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{% url "msite.views.car_info" %}" method="GET" name="listform">
        {{ form.model }}
        {{ form.make }}
        <button>Find</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Hope this help: http://tech.nickserra.com/2011/06/03/django-forms-adding-a-blank-option-to-a-required-choice-field/

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I did try that hoping that it would work but no it did not.  Now I have both my ChoiceField with a '' for value and '-----' being displayed.  Still, everything comes back as invalid.  I added some more code to my question.

Comment: Since your second ChoiceField has no `choices`, django doesn't know how to validate it, which is why its always failing. You need to overwrite the `save` method of your form to make sure that a combination of two fields makes the form valid or invalid.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid, thanks for your comment.  So you're saying to have a `def save()` in my `views.py` that essentially checks if both form fields have a selection?  I'm not quite sure how to do that...

Comment: Not in your views, in your forms. See [this section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other), and its `clean()` not `save()` that you should customize.

Comment: @Burhan Khalid: Oooh, that link was very helpful.  I edited my question to include `clean()` but I am not quite getting it to work perfectly yet.  I am populating the second ChoiceField with values in a dictionary using JQuery.  I found that if I remove the second ChoiceField and simply did a test of whether or not the first ChoiceField was selected or not, the `is_valid` check works and all is well.  It's when I add the second ChoiceField in that all is shot to hell.

Answer (score 0):

**You have some errors in your code:**

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form)
     model = forms.ChoiceField(choices=cars required=True)
     make = forms.ChoiceField(required=True)
```

**change to:**

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form)
     model = forms.CharField(max_length=20, choices=cars, default=cars[0][0])
     # add other code if you like
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Are you sure it is `CharField`?  I want it to be a `ChoiceField`